# php read contents of file on shared directory

Tags: php

I have a laptop running a server and I want to read a text file which is mounted on a raspberry pi. I have shared the Pi directory on the windows network and can access this folder ok. I have got a PHP script that can open a file on the localhost drive and display the contents, but I cannot get it to read from the shared Pi folders.

The following is a simple php script which is suppose to read the file and display the contents.

```
<?php
 $data = file_get_contents('file:///Y:/test1.txt');
 echo ($data);
 ?>
```

I can access the folder through the windows explorer so it has been shared correct. I can also see the contents of the file if I put the following in google explorer

```
 file:///Y:/test1.txt
```

Is there a way to do this easily or i need to think of a different approach. I see others have tried this but cannot see how they have got this to work

I have read about having to change the reg file in the windows machine.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
RestrictNullSessAccess to key 0 which I have done but still does not work

Comment: I don't think php can access random locations in your systems but I could be wrong.

Comment: just to add the computer trying to access the raspberry pi has apache server running. Not sure if this is of any help